# Error with subplot of histograms in Notebook Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

What am I doing wrong? I've just started learning Python instead of R.
I'm trying to accomplish three histograms next to each other. Each of them is grouped by another airport from column origin.

[This is how I want it too look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jD3y.png)

[I can do sth like this, but it's not enough for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMAS7.png)

packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

First I tried with seaborn:

```
flights2_EWR=flights2.loc[flights2['origin'] == 'EWR']
histEWR=seaborn.histplot(x="delay", bins=12, palette="pastel",
                 data=flights2_EWR)
```

There is code with matplotlib

```
flights2_EWR=flights2.loc[flights2['origin'] == 'EWR']
histEWR=plt.hist(x="delay", bins=12, 
                 data=flights2_EWR)

flights2_JFK=flights2.loc[flights2['origin'] == 'JFK']
histJFK=plt.hist(x="delay", bins=12,
                 data=flights2_JFK)

flights2_LGA=flights2.loc[flights2['origin'] == 'LGA']
histLGA=plt.hist(x="delay", bins=12, 
                 data=flights2_LGA)

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1) 
plt.hist(histEWR)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)  
plt.hist(histJFK)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)  
plt.hist(histLGA)
plt.show()
```

**TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Rectangle' and 'Rectangle'**

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You can achieve this using **seaborn distplot** and the `col = origin` (JFK, EWR, LGA). It will create multiple subplots the way you are looking for. As I don't have the data you are referring to, used penguins dataset available by default in seaborn.

**Code**

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins") # Not required in your case as you already have your flights2 dataframe
sns.displot(penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", col="sex", bins=12, hue = 'sex', palette="pastel")
```

**Output Graph**
[image: Graph]